# Checking Audio buffer for sound

Tags: c++, winapi, voip

I have a program where I am recording 24/7 a 1.5sec audio buffer from the microphone.
Now, instead of sending the buffer (which has no sound at all) to the server, which just makes it more laggy and wastes the bandwith, I want to check wheter the buffer has sound in it or not..

The buffer looks like this :

```
    short int *waveIn = new short int[NUMPTS];
```

where :

```
const double seconds = 1;
const int sampleRate = 8000;
const int NUMPTS = sampleRate * seconds;
```

So, I have an array of short ints which has 8000 cells, which stores the audio buffer...

Now, from checking with the Visual Studio Debugger, after I've been capturing the microphone audio into the buffer, the buffer looks like this :

```
waveIn[0] = -125
waveIn[1] = -780;
waveIn[2] = -1320;
```

and so on...

Now, I need to detect using this buffer, if it has captured audio, or it is just a buffer containing no sound...

After running it couple of times, I've noticed that when the buffer does have sound inside it, the cells contain smaller numbers. for example, an array with sound in it will often look like this :

```
waveIn[0] = -1300;
waveIn[1] = -3200;
waveIn[2] = -2400;
```

Now, my problem is, that some times, the buffer that contains the audio, has big numbers (that are closer to the 0), even though theres sound inside..

So for example, some times the cells can have numbers in range of -600 ~ -1200 and have nothing inside them, and some times, they can have numbers in range of -600 ~ 1200 and actually contains sound inside..

So, How can I detect wheter a audio buffer has sound inside or not ?

I hope I was clear enough...

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention, I'm useing Wave API to handle the audio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using WAVE_FORMAT_PCM the individual samples can range between 32K and -32K, with silence being small numbers near 0. To compute the magnitude of the sound you should take the absolute value of a number of samples (positive and negative samples are equally significant), then average them. Looking at only 3 samples is very inadequate (that's only 3/8000th of second) so pick an interval comparable to a real sound, such as a few tenths of a second. There is no magic magnitude threshold that means sound is present, so a better strategy is to compare the magnitude of successive intervals, or even a running average, looking for a change from low (near-quiet) to substantially higher (louder). So you will have a moving threshold based on the background noise level.

Comment: Yes, I'm using WAVE_FORMAT_PCM.

So, I need to make an average of the array cells, and then what ?
see if each cell is too far away from the average? I didnt really understand what do I need to do after getting to the average...

Comment: If "cell" means one individual sample then no, don't compare them. They are very erratic. Look only at the average magnitudes. When they rise suddenly that is the start of a sound. If you examine a WAV file in an audio editor (like CoolEdit) you will get a better feel for what this data looks like.

Comment: so if I can make it more understandable, you're saying something like that :

Get the average value on the array. if it is less then X (for example, X may be -800), it is a good packet. otherwise, it is a bad packet.

Is this what you've ment ?

Comment: Did you take the absolute value of the samples before averaging them? That can't possibly be a negative value. And I don't know what you mean by "good" and "bad" packets.

Comment: Ok, I havent tried it becuase I didnt completely understand what you've ment. Let me explain better :

1) Good packet = a buffer with a sound in it. Bad packet = a buffer that has no sound in it, just void (like, silence, because I dont speak to the microphone, and also, my room has complete silence in it too).
2) If I understand correctly, I need to : create an average using the absolute value of the array, and then check if the average is bigger then X? if it is, then it is a "good packet" ?

Comment: Yes. Then you have to figure out a good way to decide X based on the observed silence level. (It might change.)

Comment: Ok. So how can I figure the X ? is there any way, or I just have to keep trying-failing untill I get it right ?

Comment: Okay, I've been using X as 950, and it's been going pretty well! Only few times empty packets get higher then 950... :) Thanks a lot! If there is a better way to determine the X then just to try and check over and over, please let me know!

Comment: Glad you are making progress. I already suggested a better way to determine X, up where it says "no magic". I don't think I can explain it any clearer.

Comment: Which better way? You've only said -  "Then you have to figure out a good way to decide X based on the observed silence level"